# How do I get Auto Archive for Outlook 2010 to work on all folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, archiving

In my outlook 2010, i have setup auto-archiving for one folder and then selected to apply the settings to all folders.  The auto-archive is set to run every 3 days.  The auto-archive does run however, it doesn't move any emails.  If i manually click on an individual folder and tell it to archive based on it's auto-archive settings, it works perfectly.  So I know that my folder path and all associated settings are correct because it works when i manually run the archive for each individual folder.  I also know that the auto-archive runs on its schedule, but for some reason, it doesn't actually do anything.  What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Within the AutoArchive configuration setting it states:

[image]

Right clicking on a random folder I found the below settings, - have you checked to make sure that the rules are set correctly here?

[image]

Comment: Yes.  I have checked this.  All of my folders have the correct archive settings.  They are set to the second radio button "Archive items in this folder using the default settings."  I have verified the default settings and they are correct.  I know they are correct also because when i manually run each folder, it works.